# Python Twitter Scraper Without Using API

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, twint

I am trying to make a Twitter Scraper using python using twint module but I think twitter block this module.

When Running Twint Module I got this error. Can anyone give me any other way to scrape twitter twits.

...

```
CRITICAL:root:twint.run:Twint:Feed:noDataExpecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
sleeping for 1.0 secs
CRITICAL:root:twint.run:Twint:Feed:noDataExpecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
sleeping for 1.0 secs
CRITICAL:root:twint.run:Twint:Feed:noDataExpecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
sleeping for 1.0 secs
CRITICAL:root:twint.run:Twint:Feed:noDataExpecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
sleeping for 1.0 secs
CRITICAL:root:twint.run:Twint:Feed:noDataExpecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
sleeping for 1.0 secs
CRITICAL:root:twint.run:Twint:Feed:noDataExpecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
sleeping for 1.0 secs
CRITICAL:root:twint.run:Twint:Feed:noDataExpecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
sleeping for 1.0 secs
```

...

My Code

...

```
import twint

#Configure
c = twint.Config()
c.Search = "covid"

#Run
twint.run.Search(c)
```

...

Comment: Have you tried using [`twitterscraper`](https://github.com/taspinar/twitterscraper)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Uninstall twint

`pip3 uninstall twint`

than install twint using

`pip3 install --user --upgrade git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint`

this works for me.

Comment: FWiW, I tried the above command but it didn't work until I wrapped the last argument in quotes like this: `pip3 install --user --upgrade "git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint"`